# Converting PrintContainer Preprocessor Define into Template in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I've got the following preprocessor define:

```
#define PRINTARRAY(Type, Array, Stream, Separator) \
std::copy(std::begin(Array), std::end(Array), std::ostream_iterator<Type>(Stream, Separator))
```

I'm wanting to convert this to a template, so it can automatically determine the type for the ostream_iterator, so I don't have to pass it in.

However, I'm wondering what how to do this. My key issues are:

- Getting this to work with all STL containers
- Getting this to work with ordinary arrays (which std::begin / end supports?)

I think the key issue is that the ostream_iterator, afaik, needs to have the type of the contained values, and not the type of the container.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
template <class Con, class Stream>
void print_container(const Con& container, Stream& stream, const typename Stream::char_type* c) {
    using value_type = typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*std::begin(container))>::typ‌​e;
    std::copy(std::begin(container), std::end(container), std::ostream_iterator<value_type>(stream, &c);
}
```

And then

```
std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
print_container(v, std::cerr, " ");
int a [] = {4, 5, 6};
print_container(a, std::cerr, " ");
```

Prints

1 2 3 4 5 6

I should probably mention, btw when you say "all STL containers", this still cannot work with all STL containers, because many STL containers (like all of the maps) actually iterate over `std::pair`s of something. And `std::pair` does not have `<<` or anything equivalent defined, so this will not work for those.

Comment: You don't need `typename` in `value_type`. Also `char` cannot be used as a parameter identifier.

Comment: Suggest `using value_type = std::remove_reference<decltype(*std::begin(container))>::type;`

Comment: Hah yeah pretty poorly named parameter, thanks for corrections.

Comment: @RSahu I added that correct as well. Though when I run this code I actually see weird output.

Comment: @NirFriedman, you need to use just `c`, not `&c` to construct the `ostream_iterator`.

Comment: @RSahu http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator/ostream_iterator Seems to indicate that the constructor takes a pointer... is this a typo?

Comment: @NirFriedman, my mistake. It needs to be a null terminated string, not just a `char*`.

Comment: Nice solution (+1) but I suppose you can semplify it: if I'm not wrong, you can avoid the third template parameter (`Char`) and use `Stream::char_type` instead.

Comment: @max66 I think that's correct, I'll make the change, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, STL containers have an alias `value_type` that denotes the type of objects the container holds. So you can use it to get the type of the contained element. But that fails for raw arrays. In which case you can use `decltype(*std::begin(c))` to deduce the type. A generic solution will be:

```
template<typename Container>
void PrintArray(std::ostream& Stream, const char* Separator, const Container& c){
    std::copy(std::begin(c), std::end(c), std::ostream_iterator<decltype(*std::begin(c))>(Stream, Separator));
}
```

Example usage:

```
std::vector<int> v0{1,2 ,3, 5};
PrintArray(std::cout, " ", v0);
```

As seen [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e0948094cc2371d)

Comment: @NathanOliver, Ahh,,, didn't see that part. Corrected